# readline: unknown key modifier

Tags: bash, readline

I am attempting to set `revert-all-at-newline on` in my bash config file.

```
bind 'revert-all-at-newline on'
```

However, this throws the error

```
readline: revert-all-at-newline: unknown key modifier
```

`bind` does not appear to have it

```
$ bind -l | grep revert-all-at-newline
$
```

But it is in the `man readline` documentation locally.

How can I get set the `revert-all-at-newline` config variable?

- bash version 4.4.2
- readline version 7.0

Comment: bind -V | grep revert-all-at-newline

Comment: bind 'set revert-all-at-newline On'

Comment: @bac0n `bind -V | grep revert` tells me it is already "on", but now I wonder why my history is still being rewritten permanently. When I use `bind 'set ...' like you suggested, the error goes away, but that's not the syntax the documentation says to use (no "set"), so I think it might be getting ignored.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: shopt -s histappend # append to the history file, don't overwrite it ?

Answer (score 1):

As @bac0n mentioned, you should use

```
bind 'set revert-all-at-newline on'
```

Instead of

```
bind 'revert-all-at-newline on'
```

`set` did the trick!